# Not able to display one item from query result - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So, weird issue.

Here's the code:

```
//connect and execute query
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','user','password');
@mysql_select_db('db_name') or die( "Unable to select database");

$query="SELECT node_revisions.nid, node_revisions.title, content_type_training_event.field_course_url_value
    FROM node_revisions, content_type_training_event
    WHERE body LIKE '%{$term}%' AND node_revisions.nid IN (SELECT nid FROM content_type_training_event) AND content_type_training_event.nid = node_revisions.nid";

$result=mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_numrows($result);  

if ($num > 0)
{
while ($col = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{       

$nid=trim($col["nid"]);
$title=trim($col["title"]);
$url=trim($col["field_course_url_value"]);

}
}
```

//OK weird part...

```
echo($nid . $title . $url);
```

So, what happens is $title and $url are printed to screen, but $nid is not.  When I run the same query inside MySQL Admin, I get the nid.

Any ideas?  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: what is result of var_dump($nid) and var_dump($col["nid"])?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe because there is an NID in multiple tables. Alias the NID in your query as follows:

```
$query="SELECT node_revisions.nid as nid, node_revisions.title, content_type_training_event.field_course_url_value
    FROM node_revisions, content_type_training_event
    WHERE body LIKE '%{$term}%' AND node_revisions.nid IN (SELECT nid FROM content_type_training_event) AND content_type_training_event.nid = node_revisions.nid"
```

I certainly could be wrong; feel free to downvote :)

Comment: Thank you adarshr!  That was it!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT node_revisions.nid as currentNid, node.....
```

And then

```
$nid=trim($col["currentNid"]);
$title=trim($col["title"]);
$url=trim($col["field_course_url_value"]);
```